# Ember Fixtures data not loading

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have been trying to get Ember fixtures data working on a test app I am developing that's based on the ember-rails gem. The data model seems to be loading when I use the Chrome Ember inspector tool but it doesn't load the actual data.

I have the following setup.

router.js

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('projects'), { path: '/' };
});
```

store.js

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter
```

models/project.js

```
App.Project = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Project.FIXTURES = [
  { id: 1, 
    name: 'Test data 1'
  },
  { id: 2,
    name: 'Test data 2'
  }
];
```

routes/projectsRoute.js

```
App.ProjectRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('project');                                            
  }
});
```

As i mentioned this is built on top of rails using the ember-rails gem.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `FIXTURES` as a key, it looks like you have to reopen the Model:

```
App.Project.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    { id: 1, 
      name: 'Test data 1'
    },
    { id: 2,
      name: 'Test data 2'
    }
  ]
});
```

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-fixture-adapter/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately when I change to use reopenClass I seem to completely lose the model from the chrome ember inspector...

Comment: It also looks like the store expects this: `return this.store.find('project', 1);`

Comment: Still no joy I am afraid :( . The Ember Chrome inspector shows project(0) in the data tab. Thanks again for your help, any other ideas would be great!

Comment: I decided it was easier to just setup a Rails API instead. For anyone looking to do the same I recommend this great tutorial - http://ember.vicramon.com/creating-the-rails-api